# How to get an OrderedSet of OccurrenceSpecifications from a Lifeline in QVTo?

Tags: eclipse, uml, qvt

From the diagram on page 570 of the [UML spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF/) I concluded that a `Lifeline` should have the `events` property, holding an `OrderedSet(OcurrenceSpecification)`. Unfortunately it is not there, at least in the QVTo implementation that I use.

All I have is the `coveredBy` property, serving me with an (unordered) `Set(InteractionFragment)`. Since my transformation relies on the correct order of `MessageOcurrenceSpecification` I somehow need to implement myself what I expected to be implemented by the missing `events` property.

This is what I have so far:

```
helper Lifeline::getEvents (): OrderedSet(OccurrenceSpecification) {

    return self.coveredBy->selectByKind(OccurrenceSpecification)->sortedBy(true);
}
```

Obviously `sortedBy(true)` does not get me far, but I don't know any further. Who can help?

All I could find so far were other people struggling with the same issue years ago, but no solution:

- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1049555/
- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1050025/
- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1095764/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [answer by Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187858/948404) combined with input from a colleague of mine I came up with the following solution for QVTo:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Polyfill for the missing Lifeline::events property

query Lifeline::getEvents (): OrderedSet(OccurrenceSpecification) {

    return self.interaction.fragment
            ->selectByKind(OccurrenceSpecification)
            ->select(os: OccurrenceSpecification | os.covered->includes(self))
            ->asOrderedSet();
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems good to me and better than mine. I didn't tought of using the eopposite of `coveredBy` and `fragment` (I don't know well the metamodel related to the sequence diagram).  The only modification I would have done are more 'syntax' related as QVTo and OCL give nice shortcuts:
`self.interaction.fragment[OccurrenceSpecification]->select(covered->includes(self))->asOrderedSet()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible, using directly `coveredBy` to get an ordered collection. As `coveredBy` is unordered, if you access it directly by the feature, you will have an unpredictible order and if you try to access it using the `eGet(...)` stuff, the same result will occur.

However, if I understood correctly, there is a "trick" that could work. 
It relies on the assumption that each `OccurrenceSpecification` instance you need is held by the same `Interaction` that contains the `Lifeline` and uses the way EMF stores contained elements. Actually, each contained element is always kind of 'ordered' relatively to its parent (and for each collection so EMF can find elements back when XMI references are expressed using the element position in collections). So, the idea would be to access all the elements contained by the `Interaction` that owns the lifeline and filter the ones that are contained in `coveredBy`.

### Expression with Acceleo

This is easy to write in MTL/Acceleo. In know you don't use it, but it illustrates what the expression does:

```
# In Acceleo:
# 'self' is the lifeline instance
self.interaction.eAllContents(OccurrenceSpecification)->select(e | self.coveredBy->includes(e))->asOrderedSet()
```

with `self.interaction` we retrieve the `Interaction`, then we get all the contained elements with `eAllContents(...)` and we filter the ones that are in the `self.coveredBy` collection.

But it is way less intuitive in QVT as `eAllContents(...)` does not exist. Instead you have to gain access to `eContents()` which is defined on `EObject` and returns an `EList` which is transtyped to a `Sequence` (in QVT,`eAllContents()` returns a `ETreeIterator` which is not transtyped by the QVT engine).

So, how to gain access to `eContents()` in the helper? There is two solutions:

### Solution 1: Using the `emf.tools` library

The `emf.tools` library give you the ability to use `asEObject()` which casts your object in a pure `EObject` and give you more methods to access to (as `eClass()` for example...etc).

```
import emf.tools;  -- we import the EMF tools library

modeltype UML ...; -- all your metamodel imports and stuffs
...
helper Lifeline::getEvents (): OrderedSet(OccurrenceSpecification) {
  return self.interaction.asEObject().eContents()[OccurrenceSpecification]->select(e | self.coveredBy->includes(e))->asOrderedSet();
}
```

### Solution 2: Using `oclAstype(...)`

If for some reason `emf.tools` cannot be accessed, you can still cast to an `EObject` using `oclAsType(...)`.

```
modeltype UML ...; -- all your metamodel imports and stuffs
modeltype ECORE "strict" uses ecore('http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore');  -- you also register the Ecore metamodel
...
helper Lifeline::getEvents (): OrderedSet(OccurrenceSpecification) {
  return self.interaction.oclAsType(EObject).eContents()[OccurrenceSpecification]->select(e | self.coveredBy->includes(e))->asOrderedSet();
}
```

### Limitation

Ok, let's be honest here, this solution seems to work on the quick tests I performed, but I'm not a 100% sure that you will have all the elements you want as this code relies on the strong assumption that every `OccurrenceSpecification` you need are in the same `Interaction` as the `Liteline` instance. If you are sure that all the `coveredBy` elements you need are in the `Interaction` (I think they should be), then, that's not the sexiest solution, but it should do the work.

**EDIT>**

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45189154/4536442) proposed by hielsnoppe is more eleguant than the one I presented here and should be prefered.

Comment: Thanks for your insights! I created another solution for QVTo from it, feel free to comment if you find something I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The Lifeline::events property is clearly shown on the diagram and appears in derived models such as UML.merged.uml.

Unfortunately Eclipse QVTo uses the Ecore projection of the UML metamodel to UML.ecore where unnavigable opposites are pruned. (A recent UML2Ecore enhancement allows the name to be persisted as an EAnnotation.) However once the true property name "events" has been pruned the implicit property name "OccurrenceSpecification" should work.

All associations are navigable in both directions in OCL, so this loss is a bug. (The new Pivot-based Eclipse OCL goes back to the primary UML model in order to avoid UML2Ecore losses. Once Eclipse QVTo migrates to the Pivot OCL you should see the behavior you expected.)